# Want to print only body part in my output not the http headers.. Http Request is handled using socket programming

Tags: java, httprequest, serversocket

I've written a server socket code that receives `http` request and print it on console.

Given below is the server code.

```
clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
while (true) 
{
    line = is.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The output is:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_20

Host: 127.0.0.1:4000

Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2

Connection: keep-alive

Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 7

   Hello
```

I don't want header in my output, How can I get only Body part in my output that is "Hello"?

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) starts with a status line followed by header lines followed by the body. the request/header lines are separated by a single `CRLF` (`\r\n`), but the body is separated from them with additional `CRLF`:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_20
Host: 127.0.0.1:4000
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, /; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 7

Hello
```

E.g. you need to look for the first empty line. after than the body starts.